# How can I get out of the lava without dying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft beta, I've just blundered into some deep lava and am on fire, but I hit escape to pause the game before I died.  What can I do while the game is in this paused state to get out of the lava?

I'm on Mac OSX.

Comment: Good luck! I'm betting that short of external mods that move your character's current position (and the mac will have fewer of those, unfortunately) you're most likely boned. I hope you weren't carrying anything particular valuable on your person?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer:  This happened near the end of a mining run so unfortunately my inventory was full and I happened to have been particularly lucky with diamonds.  I had already been killed by a creeper and reclaimed my stuff, but the creepers just kept coming and coming and while frantically trying to get away I fell down a few blocks into a lava pool that I think the creepers uncovered.  :(

Comment: you could of course use an inventory editor (like [this](http://nathancmatthews.com/mcinvedit/), didn't test it though), remember what you got, die, give you your stuff back...

Comment: How could this question become so famous?

Comment: @John It was posted while the game's popularity was at its peak, and it's quite an essential question that many must have asked themselves ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, backup your world directory so you can try things over and over again. (Although you should remember that you might spent more time trying to rescue yourself than you'd need to get your stuff again)

Then set the difficulty to peaceful which slows your dying (but doesn't prevent it!). Now if you have some blocks in your inventory on a hotkey, after unpausing immediately look down, switch to the blocks and hold <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (jump) and hold right click. If you're lucky this is fast enough to build a tower out of the lava (which is hopefully not too deep). You'll still be burning, which doesn't kill you on peaceful, but if you have a bucket of water put that on the side of your tower to get a small waterfall which also obsidianizes the lava below. Good luck!

Alternatively you can use a map tool to change the lava pool you're in into water, but that would *really* be cheating.

Comment: I haven't had much luck placing the last block directly below me when in lava or water.  Perhaps placing the block directly in front and then jumping on it would be a better approach.

Comment: Yeah, often lava is deceptively deep such that even if you're in it and looking down placing a block won't take. :(  This is why when I'm dealing with lava I always create a shower nearby! :)

Answer (score 7):

Grab yourself [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-173/), and change your character's location so they're not in the lava. For extra safety, place them in water to extinguish any residual flaming.

Answer (score 3):

Change the difficulty to the easiest setting, this will let you regenerate health quicker and reduce the damage you take from the lava, if you're lucky then it may buy you just enough time to get clear of the lava.

Answer (score 0):

Use MCedit if you want. Also,if you worn armour,attempt to get out of lava,then go quickly to the closest water source. To prevent this happening again in the future,keep on a hot slot(inventory bar) a water bucket.