# I am about to die in lava. How might I save my inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing the Minecraft Feed the Beast modpack.

During a lengthy mining session, I made a dumb mistake and fell into lava (not for the first time).

I rage-quit the game before I died, and now I would like to know if there is any way of rescuing my inventory.

I know about the `/gamerule` command, but I won't have enough time to enter it before I die.  I also do not have a bucket of water with me.

Is there a way to disable item drop on death without being ingame? I would prefer if I do not have to use external tools.

Comment: A possible solution is to directly mod your save file, that is, get an editor (such as NBTEdit) that can change your gamemode.  That way, when you log back in to your map, you'll be automatically in creative, preventing damage to you.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I guess i did not find that question because i concentrated on keeping my inventory. I thought that dying was inevitable

Comment: `/gamerule keepinventory true`

Comment: This question should be re-opened as there are mod specific ways in FTB of saving your inventory upon death.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I get out of the lava without dying?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/how-can-i-get-out-of-the-lava-without-dying)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot True, but these ways only apply as precautions. In the situation described here there is nothing FTB adds to the vanilla answers, since the in-game time required to do these things is too long

Comment: @Zommuter The scope of this question is much broader than the vanilla question.  They are distinct.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Would you mind to elaborate on that? Yes, this question in principle permits solutions that rely on FTB mods. But those are only relevant in-game, where the available time due to the OP already being _in_ lava, leaves too little time for any mod-related/in-game answer. Though I'd probably go for the Charm of Keeping mentioned in [your answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109882/88) by using an external inventory editor and promise myself to actually craft one in-game as soon as possible to pay off that debt...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to load up the world you were playing in and move your character out of the lava. You will still die from the burning when you log back in, but your items will not fall in the lava, so you will be able to pick them back up.

Even better, as Robotnik suggested, you could move yourself into water to put the fire out.

Comment: I used this to move me back to the surface. This solved my issue, though it's not exactly the answer to my question ;)

Comment: Of course, you could move yourself into a body of water, making you stop burning as well

Comment: @Robotnik Even better! Not sure why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 22):

There is a solution that does not require mods, you just need a way to track the location where you are going to die. So you're about to die... I was falling into lava and hit escape before I bit the big one. I didn't know what to do, I was literally a block away from lava.

1. Save and Exit.
2. Find your `level.dat` folder in your `.minecraft/saves` folder. Now back up those files to a different location.
3. Load up your game and die.

   - **IMPORTANT NOTE**: REMEMBER THE LOCATION WHERE YOUR CHARACTER IS WHEN YOUR GAME LOADS.
4. Set to peaceful and locate where you died. Now make that location safe. If its lava and in the over world just throw some water down. If its nether you will probably need to build a platform over the lava.
5. Save and exit.
6. Go back to the `.minecraft/saves` folder and delete the `level.dat` folder. Copy your back-up `level.dat` folder that you made earlier to the saves folder where you deleted the `level.dat` folder. Now load up your game.

The alterations you have made in your world are now changed but your character will be reverted to right before you died. Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde! At what point does this require a zip file reader?

Comment: I just realized it doesn't really need the zip file reader. since you never really dig into any zip files. I was using 7zip when I did this. I went back and did it again without using 7zip and produced the same result.

Comment: I see :) Anyway, good answer, especially since it doesn't require any external tools

Comment: And for any Windows 7 users you can restore previous versions of your character data as well. Im not sure if its only windows 7 users but that is the OS I have installed. So if you right click your level.dat file you can restore to previous restore points. I didn't add that into the hint because I'm not quite sure how it decides to set up its restore points, however I speculate the level.dat file sets up a restore point every time you completely exit out of minecraft.

Comment: +1 for a completely Vanilla answer (no nods or external programs).

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to save your inventory is simple, but it'll require 3rd party tools.

[InVedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/14190-discontinued-invedit-minecraft-inventory-editor/) is an inventory editor that allows you to access your inventory without launching Minecraft.  Simply put, finding your world save, and loading it should give your inventory.

Once  you have opened InvEdit and loaded your world Save (you should see your items in your backpack so far), open up Minecraft, got to your original world, then die.  When you respawn, save and quit.  Now go back to your InvEdit screen, click "Save as", and save it under the same name in the world you were playing on.  This will restore your items before death back to you.

Optionally, you could try [NBTEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/). From here, you can directly modify your save file and change your gameMode to creative.

Answer (score 4):

There is an item in the Twilight Forest mod called the [Charm of Keeping](http://ftbwiki.org/Charm_of_Keeping).  It can be found in Hollow Hills and Labyrinths.  There are three tiers of this item and each tier will save a part of your inventory upon death.

- Charm of Keeping I will save your armor and the item you are holding
- Charm of Keeping II will save your armor and your entire hotbar
- Charm of Keeping III will save your entire inventory

A tier one charm can be upgraded to tier two by crafting four tier ones in a square.  The same can be done to turn tier two into tier three.

Comment: You could also inventory-edit in a Charm of Life II, which will revive you when you "die" and make you immune to lava for a short time, allowing you to swim out.

Comment: Too bad in order to obtain it one has to be out of lava for a while, or one has to use an external tool in which case a vanilla solution works just as well...

Answer (score 4):

You can use an NBT editing tool such as NBTEdit or NEINEdit to edit the [`level.dat`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Level_format#level.dat_format) of your world, located in the appropriate folder in your saves directory (typically `./minecraft/saves/[worldName]`).

Go to Data -> GameRules -> keepInventory. Change the value to true. Then save the level.dat and return to your game. You will die from the lava, but you will still have your inventory when you respawn.

Answer (score 1):

If mods are not a problem, try installing [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-15-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-mar-14-forge-patch/). Clicking the "C" icon in the toolbar will switch the game to Creative mode, and you can just fly out.

Comment: FTB already includes NEI, which has the same feature.

Comment: Yes but TMI is easier to install

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Oh wow i just read the question again and it seems i missed that it said he had FTB sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a simpler answer.
If you're willing to use external methods to save your inventory, why don't you simply let everything burn, and then give yourself your stuff back in creative mode, and the turn it off again? External tools are really unnecessary in this case.

Comment: While very true, this is not an answer.  Other answers have discussed using inventory mods and world edit mods to keep the items in the game.

Comment: Giving yourself your stuff back requires a lot more work than moving your character, enabling creative mode etc. You have to manually add back each item.

Comment: Not really a LOT more work, honestly, it's less work than installing a mod.
But hey, it's just a suggestion , really, do as you wish.

Comment: Enchanted items

Comment: @badp The diamond of truth.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the game,write /gamerule keepInventory true on any text box and copy it with CTRL+C, Now enter your game and when in the world quickly press T (or your chat button) and hit CTRL+V to copy your clipboard (which was /gamerule keepInventory true) and keep your inventory when dying,You will still die but you will keep everything you had before.

(Note:Only do this if you have enough health to quickly press T and then CTRL+V or you will die and lose everything)

Comment: Prehaps, but you could just use /gamemode c. Also, both solutions would require cheats to be on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mouse or keyboard that support macros, you could have made one that types out
`/gamerule keepinventory true` for you in under a second. You would die but keep your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

if its a single player world just go in the game options before loading the game and change it to creative mode fly out of the lava and save and exit and change the mode back. Done.

Answer (score -1):

If you have REI's minimap in your FTB modpack then just hit <kbd>=</kbd> (by default) to see your waypoints and teleport to a waypoint where you know there is water nearby.

Answer (score -1):

log out and log back in. this way, you will be immune to lava for a short time beacuase of spawn protection. spawn protection lasts for 10 seconds. keep doing this over and over again and keep swimming up until you are out of the lava.

Answer (score -2):

Really quickly build a chest and put it in there, exit and restart without saving, or save exit and go to creative mode.

Answer (score -3):

Take a screenshot of your inventory and then spawn the items back in when you respawn.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the initial inventory is still lost. Would this work for maps or written books?